# Crystal Reports - Add variable into Text box

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I'm creating a customized report that needs to insert some variable data extracted from sql, I've create some views and formula fields, now I need to insert that data in the middle of a paragraph, but always return a blanch field.
This is possible to have?

i.e:

some text **607.61**9 some text

[image: the value of volume field]

Thanks in advance

Best regards

carlos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Text Box

Type Whatever you want in that text box

From the field explorer drag the field (Or formala) and place it inside the text box

Your done

Comment: Hi VCS,Thanks for your help, but it was exactly what I've done and the returns always a empty field.

Comment: "Some Text {Volume} Some more text"


This is how your Text Box would look like

Comment: Hi VCS,Thanks for your help, I've done exactly as you had explain, but the result was blanc. To check if there are something wrong with my report Ive create a new one and works!! there was something in my report that make the error.

Comment: It works, life saver! If anyone want to watch video tutorial, ref https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9PaNPtwdzOA